# VS Code Regular Expression Search only UPPERCASE letters

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

In VS Code I want to make the following search and replace, but it is not matching only uppercase letters.  Is this a bug/deficiency or am I missing something?

Find: `\{\$([A-Z_]+)\}`
Replace: `{$1}`

so this:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    generarEstado('{$GRAPH_BY_STATUS} ','{$nombreSitio}','{$nombreSitioCorto}');
    generarSexo('{$GRAPH_BY_SEX} ','{$nombreSitio}','{$nombreSitioCorto}');
    generarSexGrade('{$GRAPH_BY_SEX_AND_GRADE} ','{$nombreSitio}','{$nombreSitioCorto}');
});
```

Should become:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    generarEstado('{GRAPH_BY_STATUS} ','{$nombreSitio}','{$nombreSitioCorto}');
    generarSexo('{GRAPH_BY_SEX} ','{$nombreSitio}','{$nombreSitioCorto}');
    generarSexGrade('{GRAPH_BY_SEX_AND_GRADE} ','{$nombreSitio}','{$nombreSitioCorto}');
});
```

but it is also matching the others `{$nombreSitio}` and `{$nombreSitioCorto}` etc

Comment: Where is your find and replace source code that you are using?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure in your find and replace options that in addition to doing a reg ex match, that you *also* have the "Match Case" option checked. Personally, I think that behavior is weird. If you pick regex, it should use a regex, not a case insensitive regex, but that's the way it works apparently. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6993

Comment: when chat GPT fails :)